# string a="this is my book" if you search word "ok" the lying in book you get position of this word how we get it

Tags: c#, arrays, string

```
string a="this is my book"
```

If you search word "ok" the lying in book you get position of this word how we get it.

Comment: Question is too broad. It's not clear how your code looks like and what should be fixed. Now it looks like **I want my job done for free without any efforts**

Comment: Split it on ` `. Then find index of the word containing the query.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are talking more about a substring, because 'ok' in 'book' is not a word,is a substring.

You have to use 'IndexOf()'.  It returns -1 if the string is not found, and you need the if to protectd 'Substring()' call.

```
int startPosition = a.IndexOf("ok");
if (startPosition != -1){
    string aRes = a.Substring(startPosition);
}
```

Or if you want the word that contains the substring 'ok':

```
    int startPosition = a.IndexOf("ok");
    if (startPosition != -1){
       int startPositionWord = a.LastIndexOf(' ', startPosition);
       if (startPositionWord == -1) startPositionWord = 0;
       int endPositionWord = a.IndexOf(' ', startPosition);
       if (endPositionWord == -1) endPositionWord = a.Length;

       string aRes = a.Substring(startPositionWord,endPositionWord-startPositionWord);
    }
```

You need startPositionWord and endPositionWord because the 'ok' could be in a word that is in the start position, in the middle or is the last word of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
IndexOf("is");
```

This will give you the output as 6.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the index of the word:

```
string a = "this is my book";
var d = a.Split(' ').ToList();
var x = (from i in d
         where i.Contains("ok")
         select d.IndexOf(i)).First();
```